# Unable to filter the items based on the content type inside my content search web part

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type, search-results, content-search-web-part

I have a content search web part inside our sharepoint online site collection, and i want to show items which are under certain content type, but when i use the following to get the items which are linked to a content type named "OrderManagmentSales", as follow:-

[image]

i got all the items and not only the ones associated with the "OrderManagementSales" content type, any idea why this is not working? seems the content search web part ignore the `ContentType:"OrderManagementSales"` inside the query..

Thanks

Comment: Hi, have you tried using Content Type GUID in query instead of it's name?

Comment: Hi, have you tried using Content Type GUID in query instead of it's name?

Comment: I would test your query in the Search Center first. Since you are already filtering on a Content Type, remove all the other parts of the query.